# Why does nesting my modal in a MapView turn a 1 finger gesture into 3 finger gesture?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-modal

For context, what led me to this bug was trying to make it so my modal would disappear when tapping **outside** of the custom view inside the modal.

Using react-native-modal and what you see below, I achieved this goal. **However**, when I tried to overlay this modal on top of a map, I discovered it no longer worked unless *I tapped with* *3 fingers*.

I have no idea why this occurs. I have an example [here on snack expo](https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/3-fingers-to-dismiss-modal) so if you have the expo go app you can see for yourself. If you do not have the app, you can use the built in emulators but I am not sure you can recreate 3 simultaneous taps. Remove the MapView and you can see it works with a single tap.

**How can I make it so it just takes a single finger tap rather than 3 simultaneous ones?**

```
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE, } from 'react-native-maps';
import Modal from "react-native-modal";


export default function App(){
  const [hideModal, setHideModal] = React.useState(false)

    return (
     <View style={{...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}}>
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setHideModal(false)}>
          <Modal isVisible={hideModal}>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {}}>
                   <View style={{height: 200, width: 100, backgroundColor: 'red'}}></View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          </Modal>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <MapView
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        style={styles.map}>


        <View style={{position: 'absolute', top: 100, left: 100}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setHideModal(true)}>
        <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'pink', fontSize: 26}}>Click me for modal</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </MapView>

      </View>
    );
  }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    map: {
      ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject
    },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';

export default function App() {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Modal isVisible={showModal} onBackdropPress={() => setShowModal(false)}>
        <View style={{height: 200, width: 100, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
      </Modal>
      <MapView provider={undefined} style={styles.map}>
        <View style={{position: 'absolute', top: 100, left: 100}}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setShowModal(true)}>
            <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'pink', fontSize: 26}}>
              Click me for modal
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
});
```

Modal have `onBackdropPress`